# Can the empty set be defined in set builder notation without finding the intersection of two disjoint sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We can define the empty set using set builder notation as the intersection of two disjoint sets by requiring two (or more) conflicting conditions, e.g., $\emptyset = \{x \mid x < 2 \land x > 4\}$.

Is there any way of defining the empty set in this way, which doesn't involve the intersection of two disjoint sets?

Even something like $\emptyset = \{x \mid x \text{ is an even factor of 3}\}$ is still just $\emptyset = \{x \mid x \text{ is even } \land x \text{ is a factor of 3}\}$, or $\emptyset = \{x \mid x \text{ is a real solution to } y^2+1\}$ is just $\emptyset = \{x \mid x \in \mathbb{R} \land x \text{ is a solution to } y^2+1\}$ - if we just say $\{x \mid x \text{ is a solution of } y^2+1\}$, then that is, $\{-i,i\}$, we need to intersect it with the real numbers in order to get the empty set..

Even paradoxes dont really work.. $\emptyset = \{x \mid x \text{ is a solution to the statement: }\textit{this statement is false}\}$ is the set $\emptyset = \{x \mid x \in \{T,F\} \land x \text{ solves the statement: }\textit{this statement is false}\}$..

Is there any single proposition that, on its own, produces the empty set, other than the vacuous $\emptyset = \{x \mid x \in \emptyset\}$?

Comment: $\{x\mid x\neq x\}$

Comment: ah excellent! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

- A standard definition is

$\emptyset= \{x| x\neq x\}$.

- We could define it as the set of all $x$ such that (1) $x$ is a human being and (2) $x$ has walked on Mars before the January 2020.

But in that case, the set would only be contingently empty.

Defning it by a condition that is logically impossible to satisfy guaranties not only that the set will always be empty, but also , that it will necessarily be thus.

- Note that this defnition does not prove the uniqueness of ***the*** empty set. It only defines an empty set. The fact that any "other" empty set is identcal to the one that we have defined is still to be proved. It can be done very easily with the extensionality axiom.

Comment: cool, so $\emptyset = \{x \mid x \neq x\} = \{x \mid x \in \emptyset\}$ are the only two unique ways, other than expressing the intersection of two disjoint sets?

Comment: Any logically impossible condition would do, but this one is maybe the best, since it allows a parallel definition of the universal set by the coresponding tautology : $U = \{x| x=x\}$.

Comment: ah yes, i guess $\emptyset = \{x \mid x \times 0 = 1\}$ works too, and others like that.. thanks!

Comment: I think it is dangerous to write $\emptyset =_{Df.} \{x | x \in \emptyset\}$ for in general, it is not allowed to use the symbol that is to be defined ( the *definiendum*) in the definition of this symbol ( the *definiens*).

Comment: Ah, yes, true. Thanks for pointing that out